# Playing HD video in Adobe AIR

Tags: javascript, flash, video, air

Has anyone found a way of playing video from an Adobe AIR HTML/JavaScript app that isn't using a Flash video player?

The flash players that I have tried have been unable to handle HD video, and for an application I am building, the client requires HD video to play at a decent framerate. The most I've been able to get from the likes of JWPlayer is 5-10 fps.

I had thought that I would be able to achieve this using VLC started as a Native Process, but as there doesn't seem to be a way of doing this without bringing up the VLC player chrome (the app will run on Windows so RC doesn't work).

Annoyingly AIR 2 also does not support HTML5 video - or audio for that matter - which would have made things a whole lot easier.

Up until now, AIR is the perfect choice for the app, but I think Adobe has dropped the ball when it comes to video support in AIR.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why you can't use Flash player with StageVideo?

Comment: Get your hands on the Akamai HDCore (OVP framework). It will play bitrates up to and beyond 2100 even using DSS over HTML streaming. slick.